# signal handler not working in python

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, signals

I am writing an asynchronous video playing program on Raspberry Pi. I need to run omxplayer in a subprocess and receive input in main process. When some input is received, main process would send the signal to the subprocess.

Here is my code:

```
def worker():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '1.mov'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
    def handler(signum, frame):
        print p.pid
        p.stdin.write('q') # keystroke of 'q' will quit omxplayer FYI
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler) # can only be trigger in code
```

So far it seems fine. I can run worker() and send SIGUSR1 in a code snippet and it works fine. Like this:

```
def test():
    worker()
    time.sleep(5)
    os.kill(int(os.getpid()), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

But when I try to start worker as a multiprocess, it seems the process cannot receive the signal.

```
def main_process():
    w = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    w.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    os.kill(w.pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

The handler will not be called in this way. Which part is probably wrong? The signal is not received, or the binding is not right?

**I think os.kill is not working as I thought. The signal is not received at all. How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code you posted, the worker will call `Popen` set the signal handler and then it will exit.

The subsequent call to `os.kill` in your code will send the signal to an already expired process.

In general, it's better not to use signals to communicate between processes but rather using `Pipe` or `Queue`.

The following example is more robust and flexible as it allows you to send different commands to the worker.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def worker(queue):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '1.mov'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

    while 1:
         message = queue.get()  # blocks until new message
         p.stdin.write(message)

def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    w = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    w.start()
    queue.put('q')
```

Comment: Thx a lot! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: One more question, how should I end worker process when the subprocess is finished? I need to break the while loop after the video is over.

Comment: while p.returncode is None: ... https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode